# Laravel 5 REST API JSONP CORS request get Error 302 redirect to '/'

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, rest, laravel

I am building a Laravel 5 REST API. And the angular application conduct JSONP CORS request to the api, but I get Error 302 and redirect to '/'. The server has correct CORS configuration, I don't know where is wrong.

The general information of the request:

```
Request URL:http://example.com/api/getinfo?_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9&callback=angular.callbacks._0
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
```

The request headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,Content-Length, Accept, x-csrf-token, origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:380
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 15 Apr 2016 18:21:42 GMT
Location:http://example.com
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=4aba180c69376045bad0e16c185ac60568378dcb; expires=Fri, 15-Apr-2016 20:21:42 GMT; path=/; httponly
```

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973098/what-does-http-1-1-302-mean-exactly) can help understand what a HTTP 302 means.

Comment: Thos are response headers, not request headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, **Error 302** (Redirect to certain url) often goes with user status validation or other middlewares. For example, in the following code, if a user does not have admin role but make a request through `isAdmin` middleware, he will be redirected to the index page.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class IsAdmin {

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (session('statut') === 'admin')
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
}
}
```

Thus, I suggest that you should check if your REST API has some middlewares in the route or controllers.