# HTML form post receiving 302 response

Tags: html, forms, post, xmlhttprequest

I was debugging my website when I realized that all my form post are receiving 302 response, but it is working fine.
The way I handle the POST is through JS, using XMLHttpRequest like this:

HTML

```
 <form method="POST" onsubmit="return submitFn(this)">
```

JS

```
 submitFn = function(formElement) {
     var formdata = new FormData(formElement);
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open(formElement.method, "/formaction", true);
     xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) { ... }
     xhr.send(formdata);

     return false;
}
```

As I know, return false avoid HTML POST so I can handle it with JS. Everything works fine BUT when I see "Network Activity" in Debugger Console (Chrome or FF) there is a 302 responde from "formaction" page, is that right? or am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

301: Permanent redirect

302: Temporary redirect

303: Redirect and change request method to GET

307: Redirect and keep request method

302 is a warning message telling you that the URL that you are requesting may change in the future.

I found this question that is similar to what you are asking

[What does HTTP/1.1 302 mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973098/what-does-http-1-1-302-mean-exactly)

Comment: I know what 302 response means, what I don't understand is WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Your formaction page is sending back the 302 response. It has nothing to do with your xhr code. It's likely formaction is putting a `Location` header in the HTTP response, which accounts for the 302.  Since the request is made via xhr, your browser does not redirect, which is why everything is working OK.